# How to implement ienumerable trought code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wanted to implement ienumerable in my code so that it is readonly but i don't know where to possibly implement it. So far i haven't found any solution in the internet that might answer my problem. As of now, i have only used List and wanted to integrate ienumerable in my code. Also, feel free to suggest anything if you notice bad coding practices.

I have tried

```
public static List<GuitarItems> GetGuitarItems(string itemCategory)
{
    List<GuitarItems> list = new List<GuitarItems>();
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM guitarItems WHERE brand LIKE @brand");

    try
    {
        conn1.Open();
        command1.CommandText = query;
        command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("brand", itemCategory));
        SqlDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string type = reader.GetString(1);
            string brand = reader.GetString(2);
            string model = reader.GetString(3);
            double price = reader.GetDouble(4);
            string itemimage1 = reader.GetString(5);
            string itemimage2 = reader.GetString(6);
            string description = reader.GetString(7);
            string necktype = reader.GetString(8);
            string body = reader.GetString(9);
            string fretboard = reader.GetString(10);
            string fret = reader.GetString(11);
            string bridge = reader.GetString(12);
            string neckpickup = reader.GetString(13);
            string bridgepickup = reader.GetString(14);
            string hardwarecolor = reader.GetString(15);

            GuitarItems gItems = new GuitarItems(id, type, brand, model, price, itemimage1, itemimage2, description, necktype, body,
                fretboard, fret, bridge, neckpickup, bridgepickup, hardwarecolor);
            list.Add(gItems);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn1.Close();
        command1.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    return list;
}
```

and

```
private void FillPage()
{
    List<GuitarItems> itemList = new List<GuitarItems>();
    List<string> itemListPage = new List<string>();

    itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems(brandType);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (GuitarItems gList in itemList)
    {
        itemListPage.Add("GuitarItemsIbanezDetails" + (x + 1) + ".aspx");

        sb.Append(
                string.Format(
                    @"
                    <div class='one-two'>
                        <a href='{3}' runat="'server'"><img runat="'server'" src='{0}'/></a>
                        <div class='content'>
                            <div id='label'>{1} {2}</div>
                        </div>

                </div>", gList.ItemImage1, gList.Brand, gList.Model, itemListPage[x]));

        x++;

    }
```

Comment: `List<T>` already implements `IEnumerable`. It is unclear what your problem and goal is.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a question. Specifically, what doesn't work? Emanuel's answer shows a better way to implement iterating your data but either way should "work".

Comment: i was searching a better way , without possible bug  , now i read the answer, thanks guys

Comment: @McMuffin - What **doesn't work**? You need to respond to other user's comments.

Comment: @McMuffin - What is it that you want to be read-only? The list or the items in the list?

Comment: @Enigmativity i want the item on the list in read only.

Comment: @McMuffin - If you want the items in the list to be read-only then changing the list from `List<GuitarItems>` to `IEnumerable<GuitarItems>` doesn't help. You need to implement your `GuitarItems` object to be read-only. You haven't shown us that object in your question.

Comment: @McMuffin - Why did you accept an answer that doesn't make your object read-only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use an iterator method :

```
public static IEnumerable<GuitarItems> GetGuitarItems(string itemCategory)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("..."))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM guitarItems WHERE brand LIKE @brand", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", itemCategory);`

        con.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                ...

                yield return new GuitarItems(id, ...);
            }
        }
    }
}
```